# image tag and header content not coming in same line in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show image and header content in the same line , but its coming in different lines.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png" height="40px" width="40px" />
      <h3 align="center">Water Quality :<span id="headerValue"> Good</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know what css is?

Comment: check my answer blow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

HTML:
add .my-header class or something to your col-sm-12 element

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 my-header" align="center">
             <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png" height="40px" width="40px" />
             <h3 align="center">Water Quality  :<span id="headerValue"> Good</span></h3>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-header > img,
.my-header > h3{
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to add css, you can simply put the image inside the h3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
      <h3 align="center"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png" height="40px" width="40px" /> Water Quality :<span id="headerValue"> Good</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```